# SQL Server Reporting Services Expression BackgroundColour Based On DateDiff

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to use conditional formatting in SQL Server Reporting Services to change the colour of a row if a value is the same as today's date or not. The column contains the date in the format 13/07/2018. I have also set the field to be in date format (31/01/2000) within place-holder properties.

My expression however is not working

```
=switch(DateDiff("d", Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value,Format(Now(),"dd/MM/yyyy")) = 0, "Green",DateDiff("d", Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value,Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")) = 1, "Yellow",DateDiff("d", Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value,Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")) >= 2, "Red")
```

The exception that is being thrown is

> Argument matching parameter 'DayOfWeek' narrows from 'String' to 'Mcrosoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek'

Which is strange because I'm just doing simple datediff calculation to count the number of days between two dates.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this ? Google just says to turn off strict compilation something which I can't find in SQLRS

Comment: What data type is the column that contains the date value, datetime or string?

Comment: Its originally a string but in the place-holder properties i have set it as a date with the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the expression below (expression 1)

```
=switch(
DateDiff("d", Cdate(Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value),Today()) = 0, "Green"
,DateDiff("d", Cdate(Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value),Today()) = 1, "Yellow"
,DateDiff("d", Cdate(Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value), Today()) >= 2, "Red"
)
```

Also because Cdate is regional setting dependant you could use Split to create a valid date format for datediff (expression2)

```
=switch(
DateDiff("d",  Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(2) & "-" & Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(1) & "-" & Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(0),Today()) = 0, "Green"
,DateDiff("d",  Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(2) & "-" & Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(1) & "-" & Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(0),Today()) = 1, "Yellow"
,DateDiff("d",  Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(2) & "-" & Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(1) & "-" & Fields!LastSuccessfulBackupTime00.Value.Split("/")(0),Today()) >= 2, "Red"
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange, With this the last entry in the table shows up correctly as red but all the others are not formatted in the output i have 6 entries for [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘LastSuccessfulBackupTime00’ contains an error: Conversion from string "19/06/2018" to type 'Date' is not valid. im applying this to the rows not just one field if that makes any difference.

Comment: Probably it has issues with regional settings. Check the alternative (expression2)